# Can WhizzyTeX be used with XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, emacs

I have tried to make WhizzyTeX work with XeTeX (or, specifically, XeLaTeX), but just adding

```
LATEX=xelatex
```

in whizzytex.conf (or changing this setting by any other means) and specifying PDF output does not help. Things seem to be more complicated than this (and believe me, I have tried).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: It will be important that you also change the `INITEX` program to I guess `INITEX=xetex -ini`.  WhizzyTeX works by creating a custom format file for each document for faster compilation.

Comment: Didier Remy, the author of WhizzyTeX, says in an email that it will not work: "So my quick answer before any investigation (which I cannot do now) is that xetex might be incompatible with whizzytex if you use special fonts."

Comment: @bluebirch, would you like to expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As [noted in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86854/can-whizzytex-be-used-with-xetex#comment210709_86854), this is not possible. The [WhizzyTeX website](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/) described how the system works and in particular the fact it relies on a `.dvi` . However, XeTeX does not produce `.dvi` files: it produces `.xdv` (extended `.dvi`) files and then converts them to PDF format. There is no viewer for `xdv` files, so a switch cannot be made.